# ClickOnce deployed WPF asks for higher .Net Framework than prerequisite

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-installer, clickonce

I am developing a WPF application within C# and using ClickOnce to deploy to clients. The application is requiring `Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5.2` and is using `Windows Installer 4.5` which is configured in the publish settings to be installed automatically during installation when needed.
This works fine for most users. However, some users are reporting an error during installation:

> Microsoft .Net Framework 4.6.2 is required to run this program. Go to xxx to install manually.

I do not have the 4.6.2. as a prerequisite choice when publishing and do not know why it should be required on specific machines.

Do I need to update the framework and distribute the WPF with .Net Framework 4.6.2.?

*(I don't know whether this is relevant: I got the error reported on a Windows 8 system - but don't know whether this is the rule - and I am using myself Windows 10 on the developing machine)*

Comment: Check your project's (and its dependencies) Target Framework

Comment: If I have a project dependency on `.Net framework 4.6.2` should I get rid of these or upgrade the project and distribute it with the 4.6.2? And what's best practice for the right approach then?

Comment: There is no right or wrong.if you need a 4.6.2 feature your only choice is to add it as required.if not,retarget to the lowest possible version you need

Comment: There must be something wrong. But only if you're ok, set the prerequisite with 4.6.2. why not? And you can find 4.6.2 bootstrapper on internet to set as prerequisite or you can make your own bootstrapper.

Comment: I have already installed 4.6.2 on my computer, but in the click once publish settings, the highest version I can select as a prerequisite is 4.5.2 ?
I am using VS Professional 2013. in VS Community 2015 I can find 4.6.1. How to update?

Comment: Try to find on sites including Nuget or Github. Or you can create your own bootstrapper.

Comment: One of you can put it in an answer if you want